# SQL Server datatype precision - Neo, what is real?

Tags: sql-server, types, precision

SQL Sever 2000 [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx):

> Is a floating point number data with
>   the following valid values: –3.40E +
>   38 through -1.18E - 38, 0 and 1.18E -
>   38 through 3.40E + 38. Storage size is
>   4 bytes. In SQL Server, the synonym
>   for real is float(24).

SQL Server 2005 [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx):

> The ISO synonym for real is float(24).

EDIT:
Given what I am reading it says the precision is 7 but I can enter in my database(SQL Server 2005) max of 9 see below, as similarly stated [here](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/faq/data-types-p01.aspx) question no. 7.

Example: 0.180000082

What is the true precision of **real** and are there configuration options(ie:compatibility modes) that can affect the precision?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your answer is on that same page you linked:

> For FLOAT data type, the n is the number of **bits used to store the mantissa** in scientific notation

24 bits of mantissa gives you (approximately) 7 *decimal* digits of precision (because 2^24 ~= 10^7).

*edit* to add:

Notice that everyone keeps saying 'approximately' - this is for a reason :)

Binary floating point numbers and decimal literals do not necessarily play together in an intuitive manner. For background read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). Also note that saying 'approximately 7 decimal digits of *precision*' is not incompatible with being able to store a value with more than 7 significant figures! It does mean however that this datatype will be unable to distinguish between 0.180000082 and 0.180000083, for example, because it isn't actually storing the *exact* value of either:

```
declare @f1 real
declare @f2 real

set @f1 = 0.180000082
set @f2 = 0.180000083

select @f1, @f2

select @f1 - @f2
```

---

```
------------- -------------
0.1800001     0.1800001

(1 row(s) affected)


-------------
0

(1 row(s) affected)
```

---

The fact is that `real` is the same as `float(24)`, a binary floating point number with 24 bits of mantissa, and I don't believe there's a way to change this. Floating-point types are in general not a good choice if you want to store exact decimal quantities.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this was driving me crazy!

Comment: Great answer, and +2 for the link to that classic paper

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing binary (base 2) precision with decimal (base 10) precision. 24 bits gives you approximately 7 decimal digits.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server uses either 4 bytes or 8 bytes to store non-decimal floating point numbers.

If you specify real or any value in the range float<1> to float<24>, SQL server uses float<24> internally. If you use float or anything in the range float<25> to float<53> (the limit), it uses float<53> which is otherwise known as double precision.

MSDN documentation for float in SQL Server 2005 is here: [float and real (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx)

If you have a specific precision need, look instead at using decimal, which provides configurable precision and scale: [decimal and numeric (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746%28SQL.90%29.aspx)