# Double precision error when getting data from SQL server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to get an `real` number from an SQL view.

But after executing the query it will round the number from `6728873.3` to `6728873.5`

[image: code]

Why is this happening and is there any way around this?

I have tried getting the data with a `DataReader`, `Linq2SQL` and ServiceStack.ORMLite but none of them work.

```
 var lConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        const string cmd = "SELECT [Origin],[X],[Y] FROM [SpiderDB61].[dbo].[View_Addresses_AddressNames]" + 
          " where Origin = 5 and X = -26262.5 and Y = 6728873.3";
        var lSQLCommand = new SqlCommand(cmd, lConnection);
        lConnection.Open();

        SqlDataReader lReader = lSQLCommand.ExecuteReader();
        object a;
        object b;
        object c;
        while (lReader.Read())
        {
            a = lReader[0];
            b = lReader[1];
            c = lReader[2]; // <-- this will be 6728873.5, not 6728873.3
        }
```

Comment: Show your code as a text, not as an image..

Comment: I'm showing it as an image to highlight the problem @SonerGönül

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`real` is `float(24)`, which gives you *approximately* [7 digits of precision](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2057056/23354). `6728873.3` is 8 digits. Basically, you are at the limit of what is reliable / precise for `real`. You should consider a different data type; perhaps `float` (which defaults to `float(53)`), perhaps `decimal(x,y)` - depending on whether this value is meant to be discreet or continuous.

Comment: But why is it returning .5 at all then, why not just 6728873?

Comment: @BjarkiHeiðar you're at the limit; exactly what it can do depends on complex things about the mantissa; some values can be represented to more precision; some cannot. It is not "you get 7 digits".