# Real datatype precision

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.

when I run the below query

```
select * from sys.types where name ='real'
```

In the "precision"  column I found value as 24.

But I read in blogs where it says real datatype has precision only up-to 7.

Comment: Don't use `real` (or `double`)   if you want exact numbers: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms173773(v=sql.105).aspx),

> The ISO synonym for real is float(24).

So, its default precision will be 24.

Comment: So u mean, default precision will be 24, but in actual it accepts only 7. If so, from where do I get  to know actual precision value for any data type.

Comment: Please refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2057056/311255 `24 bits of mantissa gives you (approximately) 7 decimal digits of precision (because 2^24 ~= 10^7).`

Comment: Thanks. Can you help me to understand, how 24 bits of mantissa is converted into 7 decimal digits of precision.

Comment: Bits are binary based and decimals are 10 based. So `2^24 (16777216) ~= 10^7 (10000000)`, it takes 7 decimals.